# how to deal with the different cordova.js android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web-applications

i want to load a remote url from my webService in my cordova project include android and ios,but i found that the cordova.js for ios is different form the android's.How shoud i deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be editing the cordova.js at all. Any service calls should be made in a new js file you create.

So if you have an index.html, you should create a index.js in a scripts folder and put your custom code in there.

Note if you are calling remote URL's you will need to add them into your app's security policy (otherwise the calls will be blocked).

Edit: Refer to the Hello World app for an example: https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world

Edit 2 : Clone the above linked app. Start with this to learn cordova.

Comment: the new js file like 'index.js' should import  which cordova.js if i want to use  the index.js for both ios and android?

Comment: The js file doesn't need to import cordova.js. In your index.html just refer to cordova and your file like so:  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

Comment: When you build your app for each platform, it works out what it needs to do.

Comment: i created two local project include iOS and android,  and both of them can be used. But i just don't konw to put the html file and index.js fiile to remote,and the index.js use different cordova.js

Comment: Why do you have 2 projects? You only need one project. In your www folder, you will have an index.html and index.js. Your best bet is to start again with a clean project, it sounds like you have got yourself in a muddle.

Comment: i didn't have two html project , i mean that i create one html project to support my ios platform and android platform project, and when i wrote <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"> ,i found that  the cordova.js is different between the two platforms. Mine  express may not clear before.